# Using JQuery with Node.js "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, referenceerror

I am trying to build a simple IRC bot for Twitch in Node.js with this framework https://github.com/Schmoopiie/twitch-irc that can connect to the API and check certain things, in this reference I will be checking the followers on the current channel the bot is located in. Except I am running into an error, I keep getting this error logged below.

```
[31mcrash[39m: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\bot.js:157:9)
    at client.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\library\client.js:657:30
    at Object.createChannelUserData (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\library\data.js:56:2)
    at client._handleMessage (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\library\client.js:651:22)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at drain (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\node_modules\irc-message-stream\node_modules\through\index.js:36:16)
    at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\node_modules\irc-message-stream\node_modules\through\index.js:45:5)
    at LineStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Exuviax\Desktop\node.js\node_modules\twitch-irc\node_modules\irc-message-stream\index.js:22:16)
    at LineStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

This is the code that I am using to run, in order to check the API

```
var irc = require('twitch-irc');
var colors = require('colors');
var jQuery = require('jQuery')
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var window = jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow;

jsdom.jQueryify(window, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", function () {
  var $ = window.$;
  $("body").prepend("<h1>The title</h1>");
  console.log($("h1").html());
});

// Calling a new client..
var client = new irc.client({
    options: {
        debug: true,
        debugIgnore: ['ping', 'chat', 'action'],
        logging: true,
        tc: 3
    },
    identity: {
        username: 'BotName',
        password: 'oauth:Code'
    },
    channels: ['#my', '#first', '#connect', '#channels']
});

// Connect the client to server..
client.connect();

client.addListener('chat', function(channel, user, message) {
    if (message.indexOf('!followers') === 0) {
        var channels = channel
        channels = channels.replace('#', '');
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channels + '.json?callback=?', function(data) {
            var followers = data.followers
            client.say(channel, "Current Followers: " + followers);
            console.log("Followers for " + channel + " " + followers);
        });
    }

});
```

I have been attempting to get this refferenceerror to go away for hours, but I am just not familiar enough with using JS and JQ outside of the browser environment to produce any results, any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: check if you have jquery library loaded properly.

Comment: I can see it in the node_modules, not sure if there is a command line code I could run to check. http://puu.sh/emxxZ/f0d0b4a9c1.png

Comment: `$` is not global and it's not defined inside the `client.addListener` callback.

Comment: var jQuery = require('jQuery'); Would you suggest adding this inside of the client.addListener, I added it at the top of the script just like the others

Comment: When you say `var jQuery = require('jQuery')` you're assigning jQuery to a variable called `jQuery`. If you want to use `$` instead you'll have to do `var $ = require('jQuery')`.

Comment: `throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );` This is what I get when I used your suggestion @Juhana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to use the `$` symbol equals `require('jquery')` **inside** each module you will be using jQuery.

The proper syntax is:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

For more information visit [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery).

Answer (score 3):

Juhana Jan provided the correct answer in the comments to the original question:

When you say var jQuery = require('jQuery') you're assigning jQuery to a variable called jQuery. If you want to use $ instead you'll have to do var $ = require('jQuery'). – Juhana Jan